# When use HeavyPlatformTestCase, how to make idea sandbox visible

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I use following code

```
internal class StartupTest : HeavyPlatformTestCase() {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val projectManager = ProjectManager.getInstance()
        val openProjects: Array<Project> = projectManager.openProjects

        for (project in openProjects) {
            System.out.println(project.getName())
        }
    }
}
```

but idea sandbox is headless, I expect a way to "runIde" and auto callAction for single test debug, how should i do

Answer (score 0):

I see the idea doc: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/testing-plugins.html

it say:

```
The tests do not test the Swing UI and work directly with the underlying model instead (see also UI Tests).
```

so I should use idea [ui test](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/testing-plugins.html#ui-tests) instead